# Set mouse sensitivity lower than 1

Tags: debian

My mouse sensitivity is way too high even with acceleration and sensitivity at lowest settings.

Is there a way to set it even lower?

Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
[image]

I've tried https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=12270, but it does not seem possible to set it to non-integer or negative values:
[image]

Comment: What happens if you examine the values and try to set them directly through `xinput` instead of the desktop configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed xinput, then by following [Lowering Mouse Sensitivity in Ubuntu and Fedora](https://patrickmn.com/aside/lowering-gaming-mouse-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-9-10/), setting acceleration to -0.5:

```
xinput --list --short
xinput --set-prop "PixArt USB Optical Mouse" "libinput Accel Speed" -0.5
```

[image]